# Automatic checkbox 1 unchecking when 2nd is checked (like switch) - Pine script V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to make a switch for 2 different value sets, for RSI strategy(just for example bullish and bearish)
Can't figure out how to implement automatic checkbox unchecking when checked another in pine script, even if the logic is working, I still need uncheck 1st and check 2nd[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WLVI.png)

here is a script

```
`//Switches
switchBull = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Bullish", group = "Bullish/Bearish Market Settings")
switchBear = input.bool(defval = false, title = "Bearish", group = "Bullish/Bearish Market Settings")

// RSI Bullish Inputs
bull_rsilength = input.int(defval = 12, title = "RSI Length", minval = 0, group = "RSI Bullish Settings")
bull_buyLevel = input.float(defval = 30, title = "RSI Buy Level", minval = 0, maxval = 100, step = 0.1, group = "RSI Bullish Settings")
bull_sellLevel = input.float(defval = 70, title = "RSI Sell Level", minval = 0, maxval = 100, step = 0.1, group = "RSI Bullish Settings") 
bull_rsiOffset = input.int(defval = 0, title = "RSI Offset", minval = 0, group = "RSI Bullish Settings")
bull_rsi_src = input.source(defval = close, title = "Price Source", group = "RSI Bullish Settings")

// RSI Bearish Inputs
bear_rsilength = input.int(defval = 12, title = "RSI Length", minval = 0, group = "RSI Bearish Settings")
bear_buyLevel = input.float(defval = 30, title = "RSI Buy Level", minval = 0, maxval = 100, step = 0.1, group = "RSI Bearish Settings")
bear_sellLevel = input.float(defval = 70, title = "RSI Sell Level", minval = 0, maxval = 100, step = 0.1, group = "RSI Bearish Settings") 
bear_rsiOffset = input.int(defval = 0, title = "RSI Offset", minval = 0, group = "RSI Bearish Settings")
bear_rsi_src = input.source(defval = close, title = "Price Source", group = "RSI Bearish Settings")


//Switching variables

var int rsilength = na
var float buyLevel = na
var float sellLevel = na
var float rsiOffset = na
var float rsi_src = na



//Switching Logic

if  switchBull == true and switchBear == false
    rsilength := bull_rsilength
    buyLevel := bull_buyLevel
    sellLevel := bull_sellLevel
    rsiOffset :=  bull_rsiOffset
    rsi_src := bull_rsi_src
    
else if switchBull == false and switchBear == true
    rsilength := bear_rsilength
    buyLevel := bear_buyLevel
    sellLevel:= bear_sellLevel
    rsiOffset :=  bear_rsiOffset
    rsi_src := bear_rsi_src`
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that. As a workaround, you can throw a runtime error message when they are both `true` or `false`:

```
if switchBull and switchBear
    runtime.error("They can't be both 'true'")

if not switchBull and not switchBear
    runtime.error("They can't be both 'false'")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for workaround, it prevents for misusing script settings